# Quartz JobScheduler dataMap seems to be losing data when it is accessed from another class

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, jobs, job-scheduling

I am trying to send out an email automatically using a quartz job scheduler. To do this I am using a jobDataMap to pass data needed to complete the job from the class where the cronTrigger is initialised to the class where the job is exucuted. However when I try to access the data that should be passed using the jobDataMap it always returns null. Anyone have any ideas what could be going wrong?  Here is the code from the class where I initialise the trigger:

```
trigger = new CronTrigger("SendReportEmailsTrigger", "CronTriggerGroup", "0 0/1 * * * ?");
        List < UserDetails> aList = customerDetailsService.getUsersConfiguredForEmailedReports();

        JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
        jobDataMap.put("service", reportService);
        trigger.setJobDataMap(jobDataMap);
```

And here is the code where the job is executed:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {



    JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
    logger.debug("map = " + dataMap.entrySet());
    logger.debug("dataMap = " + context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap());
    for (Object val : dataMap.entrySet()) {
        logger.debug("next data map val = " + val);
    }
    EmailReportService emailReportService = (EmailReportService) dataMap.get("service");


    logger.debug("email report service = " + emailReportService);
```

In the logs emailReportService is returned as null.

Comment: is reportService a SpringBean?

Answer (score 4):

You are saving the `JobDataMap` at the trigger and you are getting from your `jobDetail`. Try using [JobExecutionContext.html#getMergedJobDataMap()](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html#getMergedJobDataMap%28%29) or get the `JobDataMap` from the [JobExecutionContext.html#getTrigger()](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html#getTrigger%28%29)